# apache2 keepalive and opening a tcp connection

Tags: apache-2.2, tcp

An IP packet contains a payload, such as HTTP information, which in turn contains html information. An IP packet is encapsulated into a TCP segment, which detects problems in transmission over networks, requests retransmission of lost data, rearranges out-of-order data, and helps minimize network congestion. The way this is done is the TCP receiver responds with an ack message as it receives data. The sender maintains a timer from when the packet was sent, and retransmits a packet if the timer expires before the message has been acknowledged.

The process of where the TCP sender sends its initial request to when the TCP receiver receives its last segment and rearranges the data, is this all done in a single TCP connection? Or are multiple TCP connections required for each transmission and acknowledgement?

The reason why I ask is because apache2 has a declarative called KeepAlive. I don't fully understand it.  if set to "On",KeepAlive will allow each connection to remain open to handle multiple requests from the same client. But won't each connection already remain open until the TCP receiver receives the entire message, which could be an entire html document?

Comment: You have your description of the workings of IP, TCP and HTTP quite mixed up. IP is the base protocol, TCP runs over IP and HTTP runs over TCP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But won't each connection already remain open until the TCP receiver receives the entire message, which could be an entire html document?

Yes - but without KeepAlive, it will close once that document has been sent. With KeepAlive, it will allow the client to issue the next request without tearing down and setting up another TCP connection.

If you have a client that requests two items, this is what happens without KeepAlive:

1. Client requests TCP connection
2. Server accepts TCP connection
3. Client requests an URI
4. Server responds - hopefully by sending the full contents of the URI
5. Client disconnects
6. Server closes socket
7. Client requests TCP connection
8. Server accepts TCP connection
9. Client requests a second URI
10. Server responds - hopefully by sending the full contents of the URI
11. Client disconnects
12. Server closes socket

Here's the same thing, but with KeepAlive:

1. Client requests TCP connection
2. Server accepts TCP connection
3. Client requests an URI
4. Server responds - hopefully by sending the full contents of the URI
5. Client requests a second URI
6. Server responds - hopefully by sending the full contents of the URI
7. Client disconnects
8. Server closes socket

As you can see, in the second example, the overhead of tearing down and establishing a new TCP connection is gone. For a server with heavy load, with pages containing lots of URIs, it can significantly reduce the overhead.

Answer (score 0):

When you visit a page there are multiple elements that need to be downloaded. You have the main page but you also have CSS, JS, Images etc. For HTTP/1.0 each request requires one connection: Client starts connection, sends HTTP request, server responds with the HTTP headers, then the content and then closes the connection. This needs to be repeated for every item to be fetched, needing multiple TCP connections.

To make things easier, there was an unofficial extension called KeepAlive to HTTP/1.0 that when enabled would make the server-side keep the connection open for a period of time (e.g. 2 seconds) after it has finished sending the response. In that time a client that supports keepalives could send a second request within the same TCP connection. Then a 3rd, etc, up to a certain limit. This extension became standard with HTTP/1.1 and is called persistent connections. For this to be used the client side needs to explicitly request it in the headers.

The KeepAlive setting you see there will enable keepalives for HTTP/1.0 or disable them for HTTP/1.1 (depending on the option you choose). Based on this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#keepalive, by default it's enabled for HTTP/1.1 and disabled for HTTP/1.0.